# dzen2 and conky display config text

Tags: debian, xmonad, conky

I'm using Xmonad and a minimal debian as OS and i'm trying to set a bottom dze2 bar with some conky information pipe to it. The problem is that in addition to the infos that my bar show i have the plain config text also as shown in the screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

the xmonad line that execute my dzen2 bar :

```
myDzenStyle     = "-p -h '14' -bg '" ++ myBlackColor ++ "' -fg '" ++ myWhiteColor ++ "' -fn " ++ myFont
myDzenBottomBar = "conky -c /home/capella/.xmonad/bottomBar   | dzen2 -ta 'c' -x    '0' -y '768' -w '1024' " ++ myDzenStyle
dzenBottomBar <- spawnPipe myDzenBottomBar
```

The conky script is :

```
background yes
short_units yes

out_to_console yes
update_interval 1
total_run_times 0
pad_percents 2

TEXT
^i(/home/capella/.xmonad/icons/mini/cpu13.xbm) ${cpu cpu0}% ^fg(\#802216)^i(/home/capella/.xmonad/icons/mini/square.xbm)^fg() \
^i(/home/capella/.xmonad/icons/mini/mem1.xbm) ${mem} ^fg(\#802216)^i(/home/capella/.xmonad/icons/mini/square.xbm)^fg() \
^i(/home/capella/.xmonad/icons/mini/downarrow1.xbm) ${downspeed eth0}/s ^i(/home/capella/.xmonad/icons/mini/uparrow1.xbm) ${upspeed eth0}/s
```

seems like that the text displayed is exactly the result in the bar but without the icon just the path. If anyone can help

PS: i'm using a virtual machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add this line to the conky config file :

```
out_to_x no
```

This line tell conky to run in the background and not to output the results directly to the X.